# Array Out of bounds error

Tags: android, base64, sharedpreferences, password-encryption, javax.crypto

I am trying to encode my sharedPreferences username and password using Base64 but when running my program in eclipse emulator, I receive and error message saying "Array out of bounds". I’m not sure what this error means and how to correct it.

Logcat:

```
10-06 13:51:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(4272): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 13:51:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(4272): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
10-06 13:51:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at com.SharedPreferences.Login.SharedPrefLoginActivity.onClick(SharedPrefLoginActivity.java:84)
10-06 13:51:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
10-06 13:51:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
10-06 13:51:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-06 13:51:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-06 13:51:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-06 13:51:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-06 13:51:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 13:51:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-06 13:51:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-06 13:51:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-06 13:51:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(4272):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my Registration activity which should take EditText string, encode, and save to sharedpreferences xml.

```
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
    user=rName.getText().toString().trim();
    pass=rPwd.getText().toString().trim();

    if(arg0==regBttn){     
       if((user.length()!=0))
        {
         if((pass.length()!=0))
            {

        sp=getSharedPreferences("AccessApp",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        Editor myEditor=sp.edit();

        try {
            myEditor.putString("USERNAME_KEY", user);
            byte[ ] superSecretKeyBytes = Base64.decode(user);
            byte[] key = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
            for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++) {
                key[i] = superSecretKeyBytes[i];
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        try {
            myEditor.putString("PASSWORD_KEY", pass);
            byte[ ] superSecretKeyBytes = Base64.decode(pass);
            byte[] key = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
            for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++) {
                key[i] = superSecretKeyBytes[i];
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myEditor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Registration is successfull",10000).show();
        i=new Intent(this,AccessApp.class);
        startActivity(i);
        }
        else
         {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter password", 10000).show();  
         }
         }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please Enter Username",10000).show();
         }
        }

    else if(arg0==rtnBttn){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         builder.setTitle("Exit");
         builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit");
         builder.setCancelable(false);
         builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  finish();
  }
  });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
               arg0.cancel();
            }
        });
    AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
    alert.show();

    }
}
public String encrypt(String toencrypt, byte key[]) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    byte[] encryptedbytes = cipher.doFinal(toencrypt.getBytes());
    String encrypted = Base64.encodeBytes(encryptedbytes);
    return encrypted;

}
}
```

Corrections:

```
  The below corrections were applied.
 (int i = 0; i < superSecretKeyBytes.length && i < key.length; i++)

 Issue:
  Array error has cleared but EditText string is still saved in clear text.?
```

Comment: Array OutofBounds means that you are trying to access a position/location of the array that does not exist. When an array is initialized, it has a fixed amount of positions/locations to store data. If you go below or above the range of these positions, this error will occur. Check your code where arrays are involved. 

Like for example, here...

    for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++) {
                key[i] = superSecretKeyBytes[i];
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use `pass` length in cycle condition when it is not used inside the cycle? Are you sure that `superSecretKeyBytes.length == pass.length()`? (probably not equals, you are decoding from Base64)

It is safer to write this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < superSecretKeyBytes.length; i++) {
    key[i] = superSecretKeyBytes[i];
}
```

instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++) {
    key[i] = superSecretKeyBytes[i];
}
```

Also, where are any guarantees that you wouldn't get `OutOfBoundsException` for your `key` array? Prefer to check this in the cycle as well:

```
for (int i = 0; i < superSecretKeyBytes.length && i < key.length; i++) {
    key[i] = superSecretKeyBytes[i];
}
```

Comment: applied recommend changes to clear out of bounds error.. (int i = 0; i < superSecretKeyBytes.length && i < key.length; i++)

Comment: If () are removed from length, error goes away, code compiles but does not encrypt. If () are included as recommended, the following error is received " Cannot invoke length() on the array type byte[]".

Comment: The brackets are just typo. That wasn't the main point in my answer.

Comment: Did you solve your ArrayOutOfBoundsException? I can't understand what else do you want in the context of this question.

Answer (score 0):

When decoding USERNAME_KEY, it looks like you are referencing pass.length instead of user.length as your stop condition in the for loop, i.e. the first instance of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++) {
```

should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks for catching this :) but The correction did not correct my issue.

Answer (score 0):

pass.length() (actually it is pass.length() - 1, technically), is greater than then the positions/locations allocated in the key[] and superSecretKeyBytes[] arrays. So you end up trying to access a location in an array that does not exist, generating the Out of Bounds error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're getting out of your key array. You should check that:

```
pass.length() <= key.length
```

Hope this helps